# add numeric prefix to pandas dataframe column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

how would I add variable numeric prefix to dataframe column names

If I have a DataFrame df

```
  colA  colB
0  A      X
1  B      Y
2  C      Z
```

How would I rename the columns according to the number of columns. Something like this:

```
  1_colA  2_colB 
0  A      X              
1  B      Y
2  C      Z
```

The actually number of columns is very large to be renamed manually

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `enumerate` for count with `f-string`s and list comprehension:

```
#python 3.6+
df.columns = [f'{i}_{x}' for i, x in enumerate(df.columns, 1)]
#python below 3.6
#df.columns = ['{}_{}'.format(i, x) for i, x in enumerate(df.columns, 1)]
print (df)
  1_colA 2_colB
0      A      X
1      B      Y
2      C      Z
```